# NodeJS Is it possible to run multiple sql queries in a single routes page?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express

Im trying to use NodeJS to pull data from a mysql database.  I need to run multiple routes but is it possible to run these routes in one routes.js page ? Ill attach my code below but its not working when i enter the route into my browser ie localhost:3000/a and i want to be able to have multiple ones like localhost:3000/b and c and d ?

Ive tried different routes and paths but cant get them working any help is appreciated

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql= require('mysql');
var http = require('http');


var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var candidates = require('./routes/users')

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//Database connection
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    global.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        database : 'irlelection2020'
    });
    connection.connect();
    next();
});

app.use('/api/parties', users);
app.use('/api/candidates', candidates);


module.exports = app;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running on port 3000");
```

users.js (routes.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET candidates listing. */

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    connection.query('SELECT * from parties', function (error, results, fields) {
        if(error){
            res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500, "error": error, "response": null})); 
            //If there is error, we send the error in the error section with 500 status
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
            //If there is no error, all is good and response is 200OK.
        }
    });
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    connection.query('SELECT * from candidates', function (error, results, fields) {
        if(error){
            res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 500, "error": error, "response": null})); 
            //If there is error, we send the error in the error section with 500 status
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
            //If there is no error, all is good and response is 200OK.
        }
    });
});




module.exports = router;
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

        res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/candidates', function(req, res, next) {

    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Is your goal to use one routes document (in your example `users.js`) - and when the requested path is `/api/parties` your `SELECT * from parties` query will be run, but when the requested path is `/api/candidates` your `SELECT * from candidates` query will be run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things going on here. For the following code:

```
var users = require('./routes/users');
var candidates = require('./routes/users');
```

Just because you are naming these different variables doesn't mean any magic happens when you declare the routes via:

```
app.use('/api/parties', users);
app.use('/api/candidates', candidates);
```

Both endpoints point to the same file and will match the first route they come across.  In your **users.js** file you are defining your two routes in the exact same way:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
// ...
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
```

So whenever you visit `/api/parties` or `/api/candidates`, they will always hit your first route from that file. You essentially have two choices:

1. Make two separate routing files
2. Change how your declare your routes

For method 1, the only thing you have to do is move your candidates code from **users.js** to a new file, say **candidates.js**, and change this definition:

```
var candidates = require('./routes/candidates');
```

For method 2, you could keep them in the same file but you would have to change the base route in **app.js** to:

```
app.use('/api', users);
```

Then in users.js you would declare the routes as follows:

```
router.get('/parties', function(req, res) {
// ...
router.get('/candidates', function(req, res) {
```

Also you want to change your actual route functions to be `function(req, res)` instead of `function(req, res, next)`. You can also `res.json` to shorten your JSON response from:

```
res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
```

to

```
res.json({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results});
```

Comment: So after all this i will be able to search for example "localhost:3000/api/candidates and the same"party" and it will display the different data ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.  If you want to the same route to display the candidates from a different party, you would want to do something like `/api/:partyId/candidates` or something and then modify your SQL query based on that id. You can view Express routing documentation here:  https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Perfect, got this going and its working perfectly helps much appreciated thanks .